# Tabs inside another Tab( using Fragments) in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

In my app(android 2.1), i have successfully added tabs using Fragments and I use Android Compatibility library v4.

Now i want to add another tab inside one of the fragment tabs, but the tabwidget throws NullPointerException, what i am doing wrong here?

LogCat:

```
05-08 12:58:57.060: W/dalvikvm(1371): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-08 12:58:57.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.widget.TabWidget.dispatchDraw(TabWidget.java:206)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:1574)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-08 12:58:57.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1371):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

// sub tab fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment
{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }
    return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.subtab, container, false);
}
```

}

// subtab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#4C4C4C" >
<TabHost 
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="2dp"> 

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="5dp"> 

    <TabWidget 
        android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 


    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        </FrameLayout> 
     </LinearLayout> 
    </TabHost>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A tab within a tab? This sounds somewhat complex to me... are you certain there isn't an easier way to organize your app? (I'm not saying you are incorrect, I'm just saying it might be worth considering).

Comment: Also, you define your xml schema twice (`xmnls:android`). You only need to do this once in the parent layout.

Comment: xml schema was a mistake but that is not the problem here. I have done this using TabActivity. I'm now implementing with Fragments as TabActivity is deprecated.

Comment: Your question sounds like you are trying to add a `TabActivity` within a `Tab`. You might want to clarify.

Comment: I have already done with TabActivity and i dont want to use TabActivity anymore as it is deprecated. Now i want to implement it with Fragments.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Any idea? Have you ever developed tabs as fragments?

Comment: Are you trying to put another set of fragment tabs within one fragment? Or do you want to add another tab to the main activity, from one of the fragments?

Comment: Yes, set of fragment tabs within one fragment. I have 3 main tabs and one of them consists of another set of tabs in it.

Comment: please look at this image ,[link](http://thepseudocoder.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/android_tabpaging.gif)

Comment: It looks like the main tabs in my app, and i want to add another set of tabs to the second tab.